# Objective-C: Passing double between viewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I have `viewController1` and `viewController2` and user enters a double value into a `textField` in `viewController1` this is passed to a variable in `viewController2` and that value can be used.

This variable must then be able to be transferred to the `UIView` as  that is what requires the value.

I'm struggling even at the first hurdle and that is to make a double a @property or what it needs to be, A lot of tutorials and examples show NSStrings being transferred but it is important that I transfer a double.

Here's what I have so far..

ViewControllerInputs.h - viewcontroller1

```
@interface ViewControllerInputs : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *thicknessField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *capWidthField;

    double *thicknessValue;
    double *capWidthValue;
}
```

ViewControllerImage.h - viewcontroller2

```
@interface ViewControllerImage : UIViewController {
        double thicknessValue1;
        double capWidthValue1;
}
```

ViewControllerInputs.m - viewcontroller1

```
-(IBAction)createWeld {



    ViewControllerImage *secondViewController = [[ViewControllerImage alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerImage" bundle:nil];
    ViewControllerImage.thicknessValue1 = thicknessValue;
    //Require modal/push to viewControllerImage
}
```

UIView inside ViewControllerImage - viewcontroller2

This is where the variables thicknessValue1 and CapWidthValue1 will be used.

Comment: What problem are you having with the code you have now?  Looks like you just want to add the thicknessValue field on the second view controller to your header so the first view controller can access it.

Comment: property `thicknessValue1` not found on object type `viewControllerImage` is the error I receive on the last part of my code.

Comment: What I need it to do is send the thicknessValue to the second view controller and then from the second view controller to the UIView inside that controller.

Comment: I understand well he doesn't make use of properties, so he can't pass on the doubles to the controller

Comment: Do you use Segue? If yes, you'll need to change a few thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems:

1) Get rid of the asterisk for each of the `double` ivars

2) Get rid of the `double` ivars and use properties instead.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) double thicknessValue1;
@property (nonatomic, assign) double capWidthField;
```

As you have it, you are attempting to assign to a non-existent property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so I have used the properties, will the rest of my code now work as this is now requiring me to use this `    ViewControllerImage.thicknessValue1 = _thicknessValue;` with the underscore

Comment: Do `ViewControllerImage.thicknessValue1 = self.thicknessValue;`

Answer (score 1):

Use

`@property (nonatomic) double someDoubleVariable;` for example to define the property, in the interface after defining the instance variable,

`@synthesize someDoubleVariable;` within the implementation to generate the getter and setter functions.

I suggest you read the documentation on Objective-C 2.0 properties — you're lucky to be programming for a platform whose parent company makes the cleanest documentation. Make good use of it.

Good luck.

Comment: There is no need for the `@synthesize` line any more. This hasn't been needed for some time now. And there is no need to explicitly define the ivar either.

Comment: ... and the instance variables are also created automatically by the compiler (since Xcode 4.4 / LLVM 4.0). Compare https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/index.html.

Comment: Apple recommends using CGFloat, not double.

Comment: Seems I should read the newer specs.Nevertheless I like backwards compatibility. Smarter everyday! Thanks.